# Chamar tela com fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Criei uma tela com um list view baseada em fragment nativa do android studio, porem não achei solução para "chamar" essa tela a partir de uma botão.

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa usar o FragmentManager, exemplo:

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, NomeDoFragmentAqui, "titulo do fragment")
                .commit();
```

E no seu layout, você precisa ter o FrameLayout, que será aonde o Fragment será colocado, exemplo:

```
<FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/container"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Não entendi ali onde vai o NomedoFragmento, pois coloquei e da erro.

Comment: Qual erro que é apresentado? Da uma confirmada se vc ta importando o fragment do v4: `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

Comment: Tenho uma tela com fragmento que se chama JogosCampoFragment. E da erro quando tento importar esse import que voce me passou

Comment: Mas essa JogosCampoFragment extende um Fragment?

Comment: Tenta alterar o `getSupportFragmentManager` para `getFragmentManager`